Axon Tracking token for different processorName: maintain unique tracking token for each @ProcessingGroup() using Axon Framework in Spring Boot
We are using Axon Framework 4.9.2 with MongoDb as the event store (4.9.0 axon-mongo version) in Spring Boot version 3.2.1.
The problem here is that I wanted to have different tracking tokens for different @ProcessingGroup() that would be used inside the event handlers. Right now I have added @ProcessingGroup() at a class level so that we would have different processor names.
Now I was expecting that token would be unique since @ProcessingGroup() only maintains the last position in the event stream with regards to those events which are used rather than last position in the global event stream. Below is axon configuration code.
configurer.assignHandlerTypesMatching(
    "group1",
    c -> c.getPackage().getName().contains("UpdateStatusEventHandler")
);

configurer.assignHandlerTypesMatching(
    "group2",
    c -> c.getPackage().getName().contains("UpdateProductEventHandler")
);

I have tried adding changes in the axon configuration with assignHandlerTypesMatching method that could handle tracking token maintains differently for each @ProcessingGroup(), however, it is not working.
Our application.yaml looks like this:
axon:
  axonserver:
    enabled: false
  serializer:
    events: jackson
    messages: jackson`your text`
    general: jackson
  eventhandling:
    processors:
      eventProcessorName:
        mode: tracking


All you should be required to do, @Akshay_C, is to add the @ProcessingGroup(...) annotation to your event handling classes with a unique processing group name for the value of the @ProcessingGroup annotation!
So, looking at your sample, you have an UpdateStatusEventHandler and UpdateProductEventHandler Event Handling Component (EHC) in your application.
These EHCs are grouped into Processing Groups by Axon Framework, which in turn are grouped into Event Processors. By default, the Event Processor will be a TrackingEventProcessor, using the aformentioned TrackingToken to trace the Event Processor's progress throughout the Event Store.
As hinted at at the start, all you should be required to do to get unique TrackingTokens per EHC, is do the following:
@ProcessingGroup("group1")
class UpdateStatusEventHandler {
    // Omitted event handlers for simplicity...
}

@ProcessingGroup("group2")
class UpdateProductEventHandler {
    // Omitted event handlers for simplicity...
}


Although you can use the EventProcessingConfigurer#assignHandlerTypesMatching operations to fine-tune the assignment of EHCs to Processing Groups and the assignment of Processing Groups to Event Processors, the default "Processing-Group-name-to-Event-Processor-name" is sufficient in most cases.
Hence, I suggest removing all the Event Processor assignment rules in your application and only using the @ProcessingGroup(...) annotation!

Hi Steve we are using unique @ProcessingGroup("") for each event handler however in the trackingToken collection we could able to see different processorName with same encoded token we wanted to have unique token based on what events each processing group handles/emits. Could you let us know. We have tired different options but issue still exists.

When you say "with same encoded token", do you mean that all rows in the token_entry table (so one for each Streaming Event Processor) contain have the same contents for the token column perhaps?

If that is the case, know that the TrackingToken is nothing more than a representation of a position in the Event Store. If two or more Streaming Event Processors contain a TrackingToken with the same position, that simply means both (or more) are at the same position. That isn't inherently wrong.

If you mean something else with "with same encoded token", I am afraid you will not to update your question to be clearer for readers, @AkshayC.

"When tried with Postgres for event and token store, I see that only the tail end token is shown token oid". "where as when using MongoDB for the same, it has collection of all events as part of the 'token' . I am only showing few but is having all events in the event stream even after processing the events "
{"timestamp":1726500801.027000000,"trackedEvents":{"952054e1-76ba-412f-b1c6-c622fa7ed49b":1726500800935,"92f420f2-7760-4ff4-8dc8-5db16549838f":1726500800991,"d23449d9-3a86-4bc4-bca9-3d9715eefbf5":1726500801014,"81f720f3-de31-41f3-b087-6b9ac1858f80":1726500801027}}

PostgreSQL will move any (C)LOB column into an Object-Identifier per default, as it does this out of optimization. Hence, the fact the column changes to an OID type is PostgreSQL specific. AxonIQ actually has a blog on adjusting that behavior, which you can read here: https://www.axoniq.io/blog/axonframework-and-postgresql-without-toast

Furthermore, the Mongo TrackingToken behaves differently from the Axon Server or RDBMS token, as tracking is simply implemented differently.

Axon Server guarantees an ever-increasing global sequence without gaps which ensure the event ordering. Hence, the TrackingToken for this Event Store only contains the position.

Any RDBMS solution (either through JPA or JDBC) will deal with the possibility that the commit and insert order of rows might differ, causing gaps in reading. Hence, both solutions use a so-called GapAwareTrackingToken, which contains the position (just as with Axon Server), but also contains a collection of gaps to keep track off.

And lastly, the MongoTrackingToken, when implemented (which is a long time ago), didn't contain any form of sequence generation. So instead of keeping the global position, it tracks based on the timestamp of the events it reads, with a configurable lookBackTime. Hence, as soon as a tracked event in the MongoTrackingToken exists the lookBackTime window, it will be removed from the token. If we don't do this, the token would explode.

With all that explained, @AkshayC, do you know sufficient about the token process? To be frank, I am still uncertain what your exact question is. Hence, I would strongly recommend you update your question to be more to the point of what it is you think Axon Framework should do concerning Event Processing and what you are experiencing.
